# Secure HTTP login in an embedded (IoT) system

Tags: authentication, http

HTTPS in an embedded (IoT) system is (as far as I know) not necessarily a good solution. Basic Authentication is not secure. Acceptable in an internal network.

Idea: Login.html (when called up) sends a new random number to Browser.
With the number, the user + password are sent back in encrypted form.

EDIT: Browser uses the random number for encryption (as quasi public key). Next Login.html call next new random number.

EDIT_1: Browser sends user+password+random number as Hash back. Hash is every time different. The functionality of the Login.html is not relevant for security.

How safe would that be?

Thanks for Answer.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think HTTPS is not a good solution?

Comment: TLS with internal WEB servers is problematic. Certificate on the internal address (192.168.x.x) is impossible. Browser reports security problem = user unsettled.

Comment: @andy_n You can make an internal CA

Comment: @Fire Quacker The devices go to the customers. Can I set up CA on my external server for all customers?

Comment: *"Browser reports security problem = user unsettled."* - while true it is not actually better if HTTPS is not used. Modern browsers like Chrome or Firefox show explicit indicators that the access is not secure. And they might also additionally warn on submitting forms (like login) over such insecure connection. Therefore you would need to explain to the user what happens anyway - and in this case you better explain the more secure option, i.e. HTTPS.

Comment: Steffen, of course you're right.  Better "difficult" than none at all.  So far we have managed without TLS at all.  I was looking for an interim solution to save trouble with several thousand installations.  Happy New Year. Guten Rutsch!

Answer (score 5):

Without proper encryption, an attacker can not only read requests and responses, but also modify them. This means that the attacker can modify the Login.html page to do no encryption at all.

The behaviour of the actual server is no longer relevant, as the client is talking to the attacker and not to the actual server.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, you mean the server will be taken over to steal the login. It is possible. Another solution. TLS with internal WEB servers is problematic.

Understand: only a confirmed certificate gives you the security of speaking to the right server.

Comment: @andy_n what is your threat? Is the communication over the internet? dTLS to a cloud service perhaps possible as a solution?

Comment: Intern our (embedded) Web-Server can be used without encryption. Access from the internet should be encrypted (safe). Secure login is important - from internet.

Comment: Another idea: Scenario as above Login.html (when called up) sends a new random number to Browser. Browser uses the random number for encryption (as a quasi public key). Both must report to the external server (encrypted symmetrically) to confirm their identity (as with TLS, right?). But everything is a little easier.
SSL is possible in 8-bit µC TCP/IP stacks, but uses up almost all of the resources.
32-bit system there is no resource problem but CA, browser security message etc. In short: own secure connection for IoT.

Comment: @andy_n The attacker can just spoof the contents of Login.html and remove all of this functionality.

Comment: @Polynomial If  Login.html sends user:password+random number as SHA to embedded  should be functionality of Login.html not important. Login.html need from Server only confirmation of random number (against man in the middle). Confirmation expires. First I want to guarantee a secure login.

Comment: @andy_n If your client and server can always communicate with a third party for the purposes of identity validation, then why not just have the whole solution be cloud controlled? That way the user can talk to the cloud backend, over HTTPS, and the device can use something like MQTT over TLS to communicate with the backend and receive push messages. This is how much of the world's existing cloud IoT systems work. Most of the major cloud providers have IoT platforms that provide this as a packaged solution.